# "Element does not define a default property" when @DefaultProperty is used

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to create a custom JavaFX element for use in FXML, but when `FXMLLoader` tries to parse it, it throws an exception that states:

> javafx.fxml.LoadException: Element does not define a default property.

However, after doing some research, I believe that I am defining the default property properly.

If I include the `nestedCellValueFactory` tags, everything works as expected.

## Java

```
@DefaultProperty("nestedCellValueFactory")
public class NestablePropertyValueFactory<S, T> extends PropertyValueFactory<S, T> {

    private ObjectProperty<PropertyValueFactory<?, ?>> nestedCellValueFactory;

    public NestablePropertyValueFactory(
            @NamedArg("property") String property,
            @NamedArg("nestedCellValueFactory") PropertyValueFactory<?, ?> nestedCellValueFactory) {
        super(property);
        this.nestedCellValueFactory = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "nestedCellValueFactory", nestedCellValueFactory);
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<PropertyValueFactory<?, ?>> nestedCellValueFactoryProperty() {
        return nestedCellValueFactory;
    }

    public final PropertyValueFactory<?, ?> getNestedCellValueFactory() {
        return nestedCellValueFactoryProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setNestedCellValueFactory(PropertyValueFactory<?, ?> nestedCellValueFactory) {
        nestedCellValueFactoryProperty().set(nestedCellValueFactory);
    }

}
```

## FXML

```
<NestablePropertyValueFactory property="outer">
    <NestablePropertyValueFactory property="inner">
        <PropertyValueFactory property="property"/>
    </NestablePropertyValueFactory>
</NestablePropertyValueFactory>
```

Comment: Also, I know that the recommendations of an IDE are not a reputable gauge of implementation accuracy, but IntellJ keeps suggesting that I remove the <nestedCellValueFactory> elements because it is the default property, so I have to believe that I'm at least on the right track in some regards.

Comment: I was originally running this with JDK 1.8.0_92, but I switched to 1.8.0_121 and got the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some debugging, I have a possible explanation for the error, but sadly not a solution for it.

If you run without the `<nestedCellValueFactory>` tags, as you already reported, you will get this exception:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Element does not define a default property.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.set(FXMLLoader.java:180)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:790)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
```

So going to the `FXMLLoader` sources to track the exception you will find:

- Line 790: `parent.set(value);`, where `parent` is an instance of `FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement`, with type `<your.package.name>. NestablePropertyValueFactory`, and `value` is a `PropertyValueFactory` object.
- Lines 177-183:

  ```
  public void set(Object value) throws LoadException {
      ...  
      Class<?> type = this.value.getClass();
      DefaultProperty defaultProperty = type.getAnnotation(DefaultProperty.class);
      if (defaultProperty == null) {
          throw constructLoadException("Element does not define a default property.");
      }

      getProperties().put(defaultProperty.value(), value);
  }
  ```

One could expect that `defaultProperty.value()` should be `"nestedCellValueFactory"`, and the value will be assigned, but the exception thrown clearly shows that this is not the case, so `defaultProperty` should be null.

What happens can be explained by inspecting `Class<?> type`:

```
 type: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.ProxyBuilder
```

So `type` is not your `NestablePropertyValueFactory` class, but a `ProxyBuilder`.

Now, if you check that class there is no `@DefaultProperty` annotation, hence `defaultProperty` is null and the exception is thrown.

This proxy is created in `javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory::getBuilder`, based on the real type:

```
    if (scanForConstructorAnnotations(type)) {
        builder = new ProxyBuilder(type);
    }
```

but it returns the `ProxyBuilder` instead, and in the process the `DefaultProperty` annotation gets lost.

The proxy builder seems intended for classes with constructors annotated with `@NamedArg`, but *not* for the `@DefaultProperty` annotation.

While this could be the case of your class, there should be a better explanation than the short exception message.

Anyway, as the builder works fine when you add the tags and remove the default annotation, I would just consider removing `@DefaultProperty`.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response! That makes total sense. I can live with specifying the property name - I just really wanted to know why this didn't work, knowing that I will likely try to use it again in the future. Thanks again for the response!