# How to properly add @DefaultProperty annotation to custom class that uses @NamedArg

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin, fxml, fxmlloader

I've created a custom class `ImageButton` to get rid of some boilerplate code

```
open class ImageButton(@NamedArg("image") image: Image,
                       @NamedArg("tooltipText") tooltipText: String,
                       @NamedArg("width") width: Double, 
                       @NamedArg("height") height: Double) : Button() {
    init {
        prefWidth = width
        minWidth = NEGATIVE_INFINITY
        maxWidth = NEGATIVE_INFINITY

        prefHeight = height
        minHeight = NEGATIVE_INFINITY
        maxHeight = NEGATIVE_INFINITY

        cursor = ImageCursor.HAND
        effect = ImageInput(image)
        tooltip = Tooltip(tooltipText)
    }
}
```

Now, instead of this:

```
<Button fx:id="deleteButton" prefWidth="32.0" prefHeight="32.0" 
        minHeight="-Infinity" maxHeight="-Infinity"
        minWidth="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
        onMouseClicked="#deleteThePiece">
    <cursor>
        <ImageCursor fx:constant="HAND"/>
    </cursor>
    <tooltip>
        <Tooltip text="Delete Current Piece"/>
    </tooltip>
    <effect>
        <ImageInput>
            <source>
                <Image url="@/icons/delete.png"/>
            </source>
        </ImageInput>
    </effect>
</Button>
```

I can write this:

```
<ImageButton fx:id="deleteButton" width="32.0" height="32.0"
        onMouseClicked="#deleteThePiece" tooltipText="Delete Current Piece">
    <image>
        <Image url="@/icons/dice.png"/>
    </image>
</ImageButton>
```

However, I would like to be able to shorten it even more, like this:

```
<ImageButton fx:id="deleteButton" width="32.0" height="32.0"
        onMouseClicked="#deleteThePiece" tooltipText="Delete Current Piece">
    <Image url="@/icons/dice.png"/>
</ImageButton>
```

I have a lot of these objects so it would be nice to be able to keep the fxml tags as short as possible.

I know that there is an annotation `@DefaultProperty` that can be used to unwrap the default tag (e.g you can omit the `<children>` tag inside a `<Pane>` tag because it has the `@DefaultProperty("children")` annotation) so I used it:

```
@DefaultProperty("image")
open class ImageButton(...) {...}
```

but then when loading fxml file I get the following error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Element does not define a default property.
```

I've done some research and come across this:

["Element does not define a default property" when @DefaultProperty is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457717/element-does-not-define-a-default-property-when-defaultproperty-is-used)

It, however, does not contain a solution. It only explains the problem.

So my question is:

Is it possible to use the `@DefaultProperty` annotation on custom classes that use `@NamedArg` annotation?

If yes, how do I achieve this?

If no, should I try constructing my `ImageButton` objects differently? e.g using `<fx:factory>`?

Comment: Interesting. Scanning the JavaFX libraries, the only class that has both `@DefaultProperty` and `@NamedArg` is `javafx.scene.Scene`. And that class is one of the few classes that still has a dedicated `Builder` implementation; that `Builder` class "duplicates" the `@DefaultProperty` present on the `Scene` class which, going by the explanation in the linked question, is why that works. However, I don't believe `@DefaultProperty` was designed to work with constructor parameters, only properties. As you have no image property, this isn't possible.

Comment: That said, why not accept a `String` URL in the constructor instead of the `Image` itself? Then you could even declare the URL in an attribute, not just a single-line element.

Comment: You can't have both `@NamedArg` and `@DefaultProperty`, because as soon you use the former, the `ProxyBuilder` is used, and the latter won't work, as explained in the linked question. Having an empty constructor (or one with a `String text` argument), and an `ObjectProperty<Image> image` property works, but you will be missing the other arguments. Note that `prefWidth` and `prefHeight` can be set directly from `<ImageButton>`, so there is no need for them. Would that work for you?

Comment: @JoséPereda Should the incompatibility between `@DefaultProperty` and `@NamedArg` be considered a bug? I tried finding a report (fixed or not) but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I've indeed opted for the "URL in the constructor" solution. I only wanted to have the `Image` as the `@DefaultProperty` because I'm using my `ImageButton` as a base class for some more complex classes and wanted to take advantage of the fxml's location resolution instead of having to `App::class.java.getResource` every time but It's fine

Comment: I've managed to get it working using the `Builder` pattern... Though builders were deprecated a long time ago, they are still used internally, and you can implement your own Builder, and add your own BuilderFactory (sadly it can't extend `JavaFXBuilderFactory`). The builder will allow `DefaultProperty`, while `NamedArg` can be used in the control...

Comment: @Slaw I wouldn't say it is a bug, but definitely there is room for improvement. See my previous comment... builders could be still an option...

Comment: Ok, I've posted it, I haven't found documented cases of a custom builder, so I guess someone might find it useful...

Comment: @pjaro You could have another constructor continue to accept an `Image` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options here, but the more simple one is stated by @Slaw in a comment:

> Use a String URL in the constructor instead of the Image

So this should work:

```
public ImageButton(@NamedArg("url") String url, @NamedArg("text") String text) {
    setEffect(new ImageInput(new Image(url)));
    setText(text);
}
```

with the FXML like:

```
<ImageButton fx:id="imageButton" text="Click Me!" url="@icon.png"/>
```

---

Let's explore now the use of `<image />` combined with `@DefaultProperty`.

**ImageButton control**

First of all, let's define our control. For the sake of simplicity (and also because these can't be overridden), I won't include `width` and `height`:

```
public class ImageButton extends Button {

    public ImageButton(@NamedArg("image") Image image, @NamedArg("text") String text) {
        setImage(image);
        setText(text);
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<Image> image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "image") {
        @Override
        protected void invalidated() {
            // setGraphic(new ImageView(get()));
            setEffect(new ImageInput(get()));
        }
    };

    public final ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
       return image;
    }

    public final Image getImage() {
       return image.get();
    }

    public final void setImage(Image value) {
        image.set(value);
    }
}
```

And:

```
<ImageButton fx:id="imageButton" text="Click Me!">
     <image>
         <Image url="@icon.png"/>
     </image>
</ImageButton>
```

will work perfectly fine. However, the purpose is to remove the `<image>` tag.

**DefaultProperty**

The theory says you could do:

```
@DefaultProperty("image")
public class ImageButton extends Button {
...
}
```

and

```
<ImageButton fx:id="imageButton" text="Click Me!">
     <Image url="@icon.png"/>
</ImageButton>
```

However, an exception is thrown:

> Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Element does not define a default property.

For more details, why this exception happens, see the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457717/element-does-not-define-a-default-property-when-defaultproperty-is-used).

Basically, as discussed within comments, `@DefaultProperty` and `@NamedArg` don't work together: In order to extend the FXML attributes of a given class, `@NamedArg` provide new constructors to this class, which require the use of `ProxyBuilder`, so `FXMLLoader` will use instances of `ProxyBuilder` instead, and these don't have included the `@DefaultProperty` annotation.

**Builders**

Though builder design pattern was used in JavaFX 2.0, and it was deprecated a long time ago (in Java 8, removed in Java 9, [link](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html)), there are still some *builders* in the current JavaFX code.

In fact, `FXMLLoader` makes use of [`JavaFXBuilderFactory`](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/fb3d08b83fe615b76e891221bc237462f5c9c748/modules/javafx.fxml/src/main/java/javafx/fxml/JavaFXBuilderFactory.java), as default builder factory, that will call this `ProxyBuilder` if `NamedArg` annotations are found in the class constructor, among other builders like `JavaFXImageBuilder`.

There is some description about builders [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/fb3d08b83fe615b76e891221bc237462f5c9c748/modules/javafx.fxml/src/main/docs/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#L200).

**Builder implementation**

How can we add our own builder factory? `FXMLLoader` has a way: [`setBuilderFactory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setBuilderFactory(javafx.util.BuilderFactory)).

Can we extend `JavaFXBuilderFactory`? No, it's final, we can't extend it, we have to create one from the scratch.

**ImageButtonBuilderFactory**

Let's create it:

```
import javafx.util.Builder;
import javafx.util.BuilderFactory;

public class ImageButtonBuilderFactory implements BuilderFactory {

    @Override
    public Builder<?> getBuilder(Class<?> type) {
        if (type == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (type == ImageButton.class) {
            return ImageButtonBuilder.create();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now let's add the builder:

**ImageButtonBuilder**

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.util.Builder;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ImageButtonBuilder extends AbstractMap<String, Object> implements Builder<ImageButton> {

    private String text = "";
    private Image image;

    private ImageButtonBuilder() {}

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<String, Object>> entrySet() {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }

    public static ImageButtonBuilder create() {
        return new ImageButtonBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public Object put(String key, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            String str = value.toString();

            if ("image".equals(key)) {
                image = (Image) value;
            } else if ("text".equals(key)) {
                text = str;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown property: " + key);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageButton build() {
        return new ImageButton(image, text);
    }

}
```

Note that `ImageButton` is the same class as above (without `DefaultProperty` annotation).

**Using the custom builder**

Now we could use our custom builder:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("imagebutton.fxml"));
loader.setBuilderFactory(new ImageButtonBuilderFactory());
Parent root = loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
...
```

where the FXML is:

```
<StackPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
      <ImageButton fx:id="imageButton" text="Click Me!">
            <image>
                  <Image url="@icon.png"/>
            </image>
      </ImageButton>
</StackPane>
```

If we run this now, it should work. We have verified that our new builder works. If we comment out the `setBuilderFactory` call, it will work as well (using `NamedArg` and `ProxyBuilder`). With the custom builder factory, it won't use `ProxyBuilder` but our custom builder.

**Final step**

Finally, we can make use of `DefaultProperty` to get rid of the `<image>` tag.

And we'll add the annotation to the builder class, not to the control!

So now we have:

```
@DefaultProperty("image")
public class ImageButtonBuilder extends AbstractMap<String, Object> implements Builder<ImageButton> {
...
}
```

and finally we can remove the `<image>` tag from the FXML file:

```
<StackPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
      <ImageButton fx:id="imageButton" text="Click Me!">
            <Image url="@icon.png"/>
      </ImageButton>
</StackPane>
```

and it will work!

Comment: It works, but It's an awful lot of boilerplate code just to be able to use a `@DefaultProperty` annotation.
Also, this solution doesn't cooperate with `SceneBuilder` - at least the one imbedded in `IntelliJ IDEA` so I will remain using the `@NamedArg("url")` solution.
However, thank you for the detailed response and an actual example of how to use the `BuilderFactory` - even though it's deprecated now

Comment: Indeed it is not pretty, compared to `NamedArg`, ... but `BuilderFactory` is still a valid solution, as I mentioned, it is still used by FXMLLoader itself, so that part is not deprecated. I didn't check Scene Builder, probably it will complain.